# How to learn more about contradictory or superfluous affixes efficiently?

Tags: etymology, latin, greek, french, affixes

Instead of questioning each word's prefixes, how can I learn more productively? 
E.g. I was researching the etymology of the French verb 'accabler':

> [[I quoted Wiktionary in French; the English version is too brusque.]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/accabler)
>   Du latin populaire ***adcatabolare*** (« action de jeter sur ») et
>   issu du grec ancien καταβολή katabolê ("action de jeter les fondements"
>   mais aussi "attaque ou accès d'une maladie")
>   du verbe καταβάλλω katabállo (« jeter de haut en bas », « abattre, renverser »),
>    de κατά katá (« de haut en bas, vers le bas ») et βάλλω bállo (« lancer, jeter à terre »);
>   → voir [câble](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/c%C3%A2ble)' et [châble](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ch%C3%A2ble).

1. The root was already prefixed with **cata**. So why did Vulgar Latin prepose another prefix ***ad-***?
2. Why was [**cata-**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cata-&allowed_in_frame=0) adopted, and not **de-**?

Comment: I think that you are consigning yourself to confusion and disturbance by insisting that everything be logical and consequential. Words and language are created, moulded, and used, by people, with all the irrationality, experience, emotion, conflicting goals etc that people have. Some words arise from metaphors which might have been deliberately obscure or florid. Some arise from a mishearing or misunderstanding of what others have said. Some from a "folk etymology", remoulding a word or phrase according to a misinterpretation. Insisting on logic is a fruitless enterprise.

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks for the advice. I always heed the Etymological Fallacy, but I do wish to understand those cases where understanding is possible.

Comment: _catabolare_ is already a borrowing into Latin from Greek. Many Latin speakers (probably most) would neither know nor care that _cata-_ is a prefix meaning "down", any more than English speakers are aware of that fact in _catastrophe_. When speakers of a language add affixes, the presence of an existing affix from another language is usually completely opaque. Consider _derestrict_ and _unrestricted_.

Answer (score 3):

Most users of a language will neither know nor care about an individual word's etymology. The odds that an individual native speaker of French knows that *accabler* comes from *ad-* + *cata-* + *ball-* + *-āre* are close to zero. They know the word for what it *means*, not what it used to mean.

The word *cata-ballein* was originally Greek, as the Wiktionary entry points out. But when it was borrowed into Latin, the common everyday Latin-speakers didn't care that it had the prefix *cata-* already; in Latin, *cata-* isn't meaningful, and the whole word was taken as a single unit.

Compare English "important". Very few English-speakers still see this as Latin *in-* + *porta-* + *-nt* + *-s*. You might ask "why does it still have the Latin participle ending *-nt* instead of the English *-ing*", or "why do English-speakers add prefixes like 'un-' onto a word that already has a Latin prefix", or "why does it appear as *im-* when a native English prefix wouldn't assimilate like that" (*). But most English-speakers would consider these questions nonsensical. "Important" is just a word like any other now; as far as English is concerned, it's a single atomic unit of meaning that can't be broken down any further.

(*) *In-* appears as both a Romance and a Germanic prefix, from the same PIE root. But the Romance version assimilates, and the Germanic one doesn't: compare *im-becile* and *in-bound*.